# can't draft a valid json to use as bucket policy through terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, bucket

I'm new to terraform and created the following resource

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "spring-site" {
  bucket = "jordan-terraform-bucket-wheel-of-time"
  acl    = "public-read"
  cors_rule {
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
    allowed_methods = ["PUT", "POST", "GET"]
    allowed_origins = ["__________"]
    max_age_seconds = 3000
  }
}
```

the spacing above doesn't necessarily reflect my actual template.

I'm attempting to relate the below bucket policy:

```
 resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "plcy" {
  bucket = "${aws_s3_bucket.spring-site.id}"
  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal":{"AWS":"*"},
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
  POLICY
}
```

Originally, I had copied it straight from the "readonlybucket" AWS managed policy json available on console.

After running terraform apply, it created my bucket but also through an error sayin gthat I needed to include "Principal" attribute/property. 
I tried both syntactical options:

"Principal":{"AWS":"*"} & "Principal":"*",

however, I am receiving the following error now:

```
  Error putting S3 policy: MalformedPolicy: Policy has invalid resource
```

Is it trying to to tell me that the bucket is not being created or that the bucket doesn't exist? because I've even been deletin gthe bucket, created in between runs and in my cl, I can see that the bucket is created first.

This is the module in the main.ts by the way, if that could matter:

```
  module "s3_statick_bucket" {
  source = "../modules/S3"


  }
```

Comment: The `Resource` property in an IAM policy is for use in IAM policies that are associated with users or roles. You don't need to (and, apparently, aren't allowed to) set it for policies associated with resources (like an S3 bucket) because the resource for such a policy is _implied_ to be the S3 bucket by association.

Comment: Also if you have set a canned ACL of `public-read` then you don't need to add an extra bucket policy that allows the same permissions.

Comment: When I remove the Resource property, though, I get an error saying: ' MalformedPolicy: Statement is missing required element'

Comment: I mean, this template doesn't doesn't serve any particular purposes, at this moment. I'm just trying to get an understanding for the syntax in the future. I'm new to terraform but it would benefit me to understand the how-to.

Comment: I've been trying to link using the file() function to a json file but I can't seem to get the file path correct, either, if that would make a difference. I assume it won't, anyway but if there is anybody with a clear example on how to use the file() function that would help to. All the examples show the path as file(module.path/"/text.txt") or something like that. I assume you can do as just pure string. eg. file("../myFullFilePath/file.text") but I haven't been able to get that to work, either. Any additional syntactical knowledge I can extract is valuable to me at this point.